# Passing data from popup to popup in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, popup, message-passing

I have a web application which contains a data grid. Double clicking on any row of that grid will open a popup (lets call it popup1). Now this popup1 again opens a new popup(lets call it popup2).

When I close the popup2, I need pass an Object to popup1. Which is the easiest way to do that?

Thanks in Advance

(PS: While opening popup2 from popup1, I am adding an event listener on Close event of popup2)

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the answer I posted?

Comment: @Jason Actually I got away by using Shared Objects instead :P

Comment: You're passing data between popups using SharedObjects? What if the user disables local storage? There should be a better way to pass objects between components.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a custom event you would fire off when popup2 is closed. Just before you close popup2 add your data to the event and fire it off. Popup1 would have an event listener for MyCustomEvent and could access the myDataToPass property. Something like:

**MyCustomEvent:**

```
package
{           
    import flash.events.Event;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class MyCustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public var myDataToPass:ArrayCollection;

        public function MyCustomEvent (type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

**Passing the data:**

```
var newEvent:MyCustomEvent = new MyCustomEvent();
newEvent.myDataToPass = <your data here>;
dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the solution suggested bu @ajay87 is wrong.

popup1 should not "know" popup2, they should be decoupled, views should not call function in other views.

this sort of behavior should be implemented using events, you should open up popup2 then dispatch and event (listen to it in popup 2).

the other way around is the same, you should get the data using an event dispatched from the popup 2, not activate a function or anything else like that.

this way, your views are decoupled and will not break of you change the implementation, also, you will be able to show popup 2 without this function and vice versa.

Comment: A bit extreme, don't you think? First of all, nobody mentioned anything about using a certain pattern here. And secondly even in the context of that pattern you can't really consider a component as a view all by itself.

Answer (score -1):

I would just make and call a new function which will make the popup2 window (via PopUpManager) and pass the object to this function. The child of popup2 (presumably a custom component of a titlewindow or panel) can then be populated from the object, or you can pass the object to it.

```
  private function displayPopUp2(object:Object):void
    {
    //create an instance of your window
     var popup2:CustomComponentPopUp2 = new CustomComponentPopUp2();
    //pass the object data to a function within side this to populate fields, or this could be done through constructor.

     popup2.populateData(object);

    //then use popup manager to display popup... passing the popup2 as it's child.
    PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup2);

    }
```

This is one way of doing so.

Comment: I need to get some data back from popup2 to popup1, when popup2 is closed.

Comment: Ah, sorry, mis read your question. In that case, when your function is called to open the next popup and before closing it, you could grab all the information from that you need from that, store in object and pass it to a new popup.